# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false when I try to access through IP address

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I published web site to IIS on Windows 10. If I try login to website through forms by url http://localhost, I can access to system. But If I try login by url http://10.0.0.101 , then after login User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false and User is IGenericPrincipal instead of expected IMyPrincipal. Web is written in MVC5.

Pat of codes:

...login

```
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicketF = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, userData);
        string encTicketF = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicketF);
        HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicketF) { Secure = true };
        Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

...BaseController

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (User == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login", true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, in this case website is running only on HTTP not HTTPS.
I had to changed Secure attribute to false.

```
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicketF) { Secure = false };
```

Now it's working.